# Can python distinguish two different functions defined with the same name but imported from different modules?

Tags: python, import, tensorflow, python-import

I was using [cifar10 from tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.11/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/__init__.py) and noticed that there were two functions named `distorted_inputs` in the modules `cifar10_input.py` and `cifar10.py`. The `cifar10_train.py` module imports using the `__init__.py` with the line:

```
# Copyright 2015 The TensorFlow Authors. All Rights Reserved.
...
==============================================================================

"""Makes helper libraries available in the cifar10 package."""
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

from tensorflow.models.image.cifar10 import cifar10
from tensorflow.models.image.cifar10 import cifar10_input
```

how is it that the different function for `distorted_inputs` don't crash? Is this not a problem?

In particular the `cifar10_train.py` imports as follow:

```
from tensorflow.models.image.cifar10 import cifar10
```

which means that it loads the `__init__.py`. However, when it does that it seems there are multiple `distorted_inputs` functions which is throwing me off.

---

The whole cifar library can be found:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/r0.11/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10

Answer (score 2):

If you import two function from different module having the same name python is going to use the method from the last import

A good example

```
from math import *
from cmath import *
sin() # Python use sin from cmath not math module
```

Same applies to your situation

Answer (score 1):

One is 
`cifar10_input.distorted_inputs()` 
and the other is 
`cifar10.distorted_inputs()`

They are in different directories, so it's ok.  It's like having two documents with the same name saved in different folders.

Comment: I know, but the train module imports the whole package. That is why I reference the package and the `__init__.py`. If it would have imported each modules seperately with `from tensorflow.models.image.cifar10.cifar10` and `from tensorflow.models.image.cifar10_input` it would have been unambiguous. But that is not what is going on.

Comment: @Pinocchio: "I know, but the train module imports the whole package" - no it doesn't, and even if it did, why would that matter? Also, you can't just say `from whatever` without saying what you're going to `import`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are having trouble distinguishing between the two, you could always just use `import cifar10 as c` and `cifar10_input as cinput`

But like @rvictordelta said, both should work fine as they are both in different directories.